# How to apply the voltage divider formula based on the characteristics of an NTC

Tags: voltage, resistors, divider

My main task is to make a 10k NTC sensor look like a 100k sensor. I have attached the first 3 images below which show the Excel sheet I am working on which includes the temperature (Range of -55 to 300 degrees C) and NTC resistance values (for both 10 and 100k) accordingly. I have then tried to replace Rp1, Rp2 and Rs with some values in order to match the data. I think it will be easier to apply the voltage divider formula to this circuit as shown in the third picture. I want to find the voltage across the "red" resistor as a function of NTC temperature but not sure how to do this or if there is any other easier way to go about this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Using \$V_{out} = V_{in} \times Req~/~(R1 + Req)\$, I believe Vin will be 5V, R1 will be 13kohm and Req wil be Req=RP2∥(RS+(RP1∥RNTC)). I am not sure how to work out the values for Rs, Rp1 and Rp2 which will need to be substituted.

[image]

I hope I have made this more clear and would highly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Which diagram of all the ones you provided you mean? And any resistance value would depend on which resistance range the NTC has which means it depends on NTC type and range of temperatures you intend to measure.

Comment: Do you mean Rp2? In any case it all depends on what "suitable Vout ratings" you are aiming for and the specification of the NTC

Comment: Is this for temperature sensing on an MCU, by any chance? In that case, there is a simpler solution: don't solve for resistance at all, go directly to temperature.

Comment: Thankyou for the response @Justme , I have made the question more clear now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the response @Peter Jennings , I have made the question more clear now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the response @Tim Williams, I have made the question more clear now. Hope this helps.

Comment: How come you can’t use a 100k NTC in the first place? For how wide of a temperature range do you need to match the curves? What’s reading the value downstream?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. This is a lot of information, and confuses the central issue; could you describe plainly what you are trying to do: first of all, for what purpose; and second, what you are trying to do?  (It sounds like you are trying to substitute a different (in this case higher-value) NTC for a given NTC and trying to match resistance within some error band over some temperature range. Is that accurate?)

Comment: Hello @winny, I cannot use a 100k NTC sensor in the first place as there has been some fault with the supplier and will have to resort to mimicking it in a way; hence the lot of data. The temperature range is from -55 to 300 degrees C and I am not sure how to incorporate these values to calculate the Vout using the voltage divider formula.

Comment: Hello @Tim Williams , thankyou for your reply. I have mentioned the purpose of this issue in my comment above and that its been a manufacturing fault and cannot use a 100k NTC sensor anymore so resorting to using a 10k sensor with a bunch of resistors. Yes, I am exactly trying to do as you have mentioned, over a given temp range of -55 to 300C. I am not sure how to start with it. Would you be able to assist please?

Comment: Little to no chance of covering -50 to 300 C without severe deviation. Sample the 10k with an MCU and output voltage/current according to a lookup table?

Comment: How would we do that @winny?

Comment: Sample with an ADC pin, process via look up table and output on an DAC pin. All but the very lowest end MCUs could do it. I still don’t believe it would be impossible to source a 100k NTC. Here are 516 in stock: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ntc-thermistors/508?s=N4IgjCBcoLQExVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogCsIAugL7X4KSlgAMzA1gAQB2qSHV1IA

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution is impossible: from -55 to 300°C, a typical NTC thermistor spans five decades of range.

There exists no linear circuit which can simply shift one decade over.

A fit can be made, over a narrow temperature range, using series-parallel resistors, potentially themselves having some nominal tempco, or potentially requiring negative values (which can be constructed relatively easily with op-amps, assuming a power source is available, and that considerations like noise immunity have been made).

A nonlinear circuit that emulates a resistor based on another, could be constructed, at great expense.  You will likely find it several orders of magnitude easier to purchase (or import) the correct component in the first place.

If the sensor is sensitive to voltage instead of resistance, a transfer function can be constructed, though it requires great precision to match the full range: again, the dynamic range is five digits, or about 18 bits.  High precision components and well-performing ADC-DACs will be required, as well as an MCU.  Fewer bits are required if you don't need resolution over the full range (say, -55 to -20°C reads the same minimum-scale value, and 200-300°C reads the same maximum-scale value; and various steps inward, with resolution in the middle span being comparable to device accuracy).

Comment: Hello @Tim Williams, thankyou for your response. Ignoring the -55 to 300°C  range, how would I further calculate Vout 'as a function of temperature' using the following Vout values? I would like to try to calculate Vout across any range of NTC temperature. I have been told to take Rp1 and Rp2 as 1*10^12, NTC is 10,000, and Rs values range from 10-100 ohm. This gives V out values (using the voltage divider formula) of 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01 and 0.01V.

Answer (score 0):

The general voltage divider formula is
$$
V_{Z_x} = V_{in}\cdot\frac{Z_x}{Z_t}
$$
where \$Z_x\$ is the impedance you are taking the voltage across and \$Z_t\$ is the total impedance.

For two resistors it becomes
$$
V_{R_2} = V_{in}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
$$

To get from the original circuit on the bottom right to the simplified one on the top left you go through the steps shown, combining parallel and series resistances until you have \$R_{P1}\$, \$R_{P2}\$, \$R_S\$ and the NTC resistance all combined into one equivalent resistance.

You can do this one step at a time as shown in the diagrams. The formula for the whole thing is going to be
$$
V_{out} = 5V\cdot\frac{R_{eq}}{13k\Omega+R_{eq}}
$$
where
$$
R_{eq} = R_{P2}\parallel(R_S + (R_{P1}\parallel R_{NTC}))
$$

Without knowing what you consider *suitable Vout ratings* and what the NTC characteristics are there's no way for us to tell you what the unknown resistances \$R_{P1}\$, \$R_{P2}\$ and \$R_S\$ should be.

Two ways you may be able to get a solution are to do a simulation and adjust the values to get the results you want, or put the formulas into a spreadsheet and calculate \$V_{out}\$ with different resistor values.

The datasheet for the NTC thermistor or the source of your schematic may give some clues as to what values to use in that circuit, if you could provide those we may be able to provide a more complete answer. You can also search for articles on thermistor linearization such as [this one](https://circuitcellar.com/resources/quickbits/ntc-thermistor-linearization-2/).

Comment: Thankyou for the response @GodJihyo, I have made the question more clear now. Hope this helps. I have provided the NTC data.